# Is there 4-player local co-op in Disney Infinity 2.0?

Tags: disney-infinity-2.0

I just bought the Disney Infinity 2.0 Marvel set for Wii U.  There are two slots for character toys on the base, and 2-player split screen play is easy to set up.

However, the box has a Wii Remote icon with a number "4" in it, and includes the text "1-4 player (2-4 online)".  This seems to imply that the game should support 4-player local play.  However, if this is possible, I haven't figured out how to do it.  Is the box wrong about supporting 4 Wii Remotes?

Comment: I can't find a screenshot of the back of the box to see exactly what it says. JamesB - any chance you could post a picture to imgur or similar?

Comment: I uploaded [two pics](http://imgur.com/a/ZyEw4) that clearly show 4 player support advertised.  Still pissed about this!

Answer (score 1):

According to [Co-Optimus](http://www.co-optimus.com/game/3379/nintendo-wii-u/disney-infinity-2-0-marvel-super-heroes.html), Disney Infinity 2.0 only supports 2 players for local co-op. This is the same for all the consoles and the PC.

Comment: Any idea what they might mean by the Wii Remote icon with the "4" on it, then?  I've seen some Wii games where the "real" game only has 1 or 2 player support and additional players are only supported in some kind of minigame, but this appears to be a flat-out lie.

Comment: Is this true for 3.0?  We got 3.0 and now have two base stations, but it doesn't seem to want to recognize characters on both of them...

Comment: Correction: it's not try for PC, PC has no local co-op. Another victim of devs porting a game to PC and wasting their time and money removing a perfectly good local co-op feature for no reason :(

Answer (score 0):

I thought I read somewhere that 4 players was possible by having 2 on each console and playing online?

Presumably that's impossible now with the servers offline...?